# DTD: Expresar orden de elementos desordenados

Tags: xml

Mi problema es ese, solo puedo modificar la parte del **DTD,** veo que el problema esta en que en el **element** vuelo origen y destino los declaro en ese orden, pero en la anidación están en un orden diferente. He pensado con un or entre origen y destino pero tampoco me funciona. El error que me devuelve es este:

> // error at line 18, colum 11: element'destino' is not allowed for
>   content model '(origen,destino)'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE vuelos [
  <!ELEMENT vuelos (vuelo*)>
  <!ELEMENT vuelo (origen,destino)>
  <!ELEMENT origen (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT destino (#PCDATA)>

]>

<vuelos>
  <vuelo>
    <origen>Valencia (VLC)</origen>
    <destino>Londres Heathrow (LHR)</destino>
  </vuelo>
  <vuelo>
    <destino>Berlín Schönefeld (SFX)</destino>
    <origen>París Charles de Gaulle (CDG)</origen>
  </vuelo>
</vuelos>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para declarar que tenga que haber `origen` o `destino`, es decir, una de las dos, tienes que usar `OR`, que se incluye como `|`.

En tu respuesta indicas que lo has usado, pero estás usando una `coma`.

La forma de usar `OR` es la siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE vuelos [
  <!ELEMENT vuelos (vuelo*)>
  <!ELEMENT vuelo (origen|destino)>
  <!ELEMENT origen (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT destino (#PCDATA)>
```